# Is a custom tableViewCell Required to word wrap? If not how is this done?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

       UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        cell.textLabel.text = @"My Policies";
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        ***cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;***
        break;
    case 1:
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Payment Info";
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

        break;
    case 2:
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Policy Notes";
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

        break;
    case 3:
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Events";
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

        break;
    default:
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Docs";
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

        break;
}


      return cell;
}
```

Comment: could u pls explain in detail?

Comment: instead of posting plain code....do provide some description of your need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not necessary, you can easily word wrap by setting the `numberOfLines` from `textLabel` to 0, it will automatically word wrap the content.

```
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```